# Firebase instructions for Android are outdated (build.gradle)

Tags: android, flutter, firebase, visual-studio-code, gradle

How do I implement Firebase for my Flutter Android app with outdated instruction and tutorials?

The official instruction for setting up Flutter Firebase for Android, YouTube tutorials, and also some other threads, has a different build.gradle file content for both project and app levels. Specifically for me it's the missing `apply plugin` and `buildscript` section of the file.

Here is my  unedited project level build.gradle:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

tasks.register("clean", Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

And here is my unedited app level build.gradle:

```
plugins {
    id "com.android.application"
    id "kotlin-android"
    id "dev.flutter.flutter-gradle-plugin"
}

def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

android {
    namespace "com.example.testa"
    compileSdk flutter.compileSdkVersion
    ndkVersion flutter.ndkVersion

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.example.testa"
        // You can update the following values to match your application needs.
        // For more information, see: https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/android#reviewing-the-gradle-build-configuration.
        minSdkVersion flutter.minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion flutter.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {}
```

If I forcefully add the `dependencies{}`, `apply plugin:`, `plugins{}` section into my build.gradle file just like in the tutorials/instruction, they just create a bunch of errors. Here's a snippet for some of the errors that I could replicate:

```
Could not resolve all files for configuration ':classpath'.
Could not find com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.5.
Could not find com.google.guava:guava:27.0.1-jre.
com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:3.0.2.
Could not find org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.7.22.
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. What is your question? Please read [ask]. (And note that questions asking for off-site resources, like tutorials, are explicitly off-topic as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. You can read more about what's on-topic here in the [help/on-topic].)

Comment: I guess my question is: How do I setup firebase for flutter android app without relying on the outdated firebase's official step by step? because when I try to forcefully add the 'dependencies' code it just give me a bunch of errors. I'll edit the post, thank you.